# This JavaScript code is not being executed

Tags: javascript

So I'm very new to JavaScript. Just wondering why this code is not executed:

```
var x = 7
var y = 5
if (x < y) {
  alert("x is less than y")
}
else {
  alert ("x equal to y")
}
else if (x > y) {
  alert("x is greater than y")
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (x < y) {
  alert("x is less than y")
} else if (x > y) {
  alert("x is greater than y")
} else {
  alert ("x equal to y")
}
```

Comment: so "else if" is always before "else"?

Comment: Yes, else should be on the end always. It's like if all previous checks was not passed then else statement firing.